# symfony4 with doctrine-odm aggregation is not working

Tags: mongodb, symfony4

I have converted the mongo shell query into symfony4 doctrine odm queries. For this, i am using the [createAggregationBuilder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/aggregation-builder.html#aggregation-builder). It will not return anything and throwing out of memory exception.

**Note :**  Even i have increase the php limit too, facing the same issue.

**Please find the below codes:**

**Shell Mongo Queries:**

```
db.Article.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { department: "$department" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    { 
        $sort: { 
            salary: -1 
        } 
    }
]);
```

**Shell Mongo Output:**

```
{ "_id" : { "department" : "IAS" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "department" : "DOCTOR" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "department" : "IT" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "department" : "sales" }, "count" : 4 }
```

The same as have created in symfony4. but i am facing the issue.

```
$builder = $this->createAggregationBuilder(Article::class);
$builder
    ->group()
        ->field('id')            
        ->expression('$department')
        ->field('department')
        ->sum('$department')
    ->sort(['salary' => -1])
    ->limit(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $qb->group()
        ->field('id')->expression(
            $qb->expr()->field('department')->expression('$department')
        )
        ->sum('$department');
```

Next time use $qb->getPipeline() to debug your query, it will save you a lot of time.